# Component getting css properties from another scss file with the same name

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have an .scss file with a name say Books.scss and a related react component Books.js in a folder.
There is another .scss files named Books.scss and a related component Books.scss is another folder.
I correctly import the properties of the .scss files in the first component using ./Books.scss but when I try to make changes in the file for a particular div className, say "tableOfContents", there is no effect on the component. This className also exists in the other .scss file.
Oddly, the changes to the first component are being reflected when I edit the className of the second .scss file.

**Does anyone have an idea why this would have happened?**

Both the components are similar except for addition/deletion of subcomponents. Code duplication is bad, but there was no other go to speed up work which will be regretted later on.

Comment: The react loads in the component structure so it happens in react that it gets all the CSS that is loaded, so try to make the unique name of the class, and it will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, turns out that the className was nested within another class which is why the css properties from the other sass file was showing up. As you mentioned @Umair, makes sense why it behaved this way.